# Which SQL data type would I use for a drivers license number?

Tags: mysql, sql

this is probably a dumb question to most, but I would like to know which SQL data type to use for a drivers license number.  In my state the drivers license number contains a letter  .  I know that there are three different categories of data  types,  text, number, and Date/Time types.  I also know of the types that fall under those categories, but am unsure to as which one to use for string which contains both numbers and letters.

In advance, thanks for any help that I receive.

Comment: Just because the data is all numeric doesn't mean it should be stored that way. You want want to store quantity as an int, not a phone number because you're probably doing math operations on the quantity, not the phone number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use "varchar" datatype . so you can use both numbers and alpahabets

Comment: @JeremyFlaugher - so my answer is correct... Please accept the answer

Comment: lol I had to wait for the time to expire..it makes you wait.

Answer (score 1):

use varchar datatype or nvarchar

varchar-8000 max
  nvarchar-4000 max